# Positive partial derivatives implies monotonicity?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a question. Does the fact that partial derivatives are greater than zero on a certain domain mean that the function of many variables is strictly increasing? If not, how could I see that my function is increasing on that domain?

Comment: It does, by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Ok , thank Tunococ!

Comment: The question doesn't even make sense, what is the definition of increasing function here?